# Windows 7 Installation issue in Lenovo G470

Tags: windows-7

I am using Lenovo G470. While installing Windows 7 through Pen drive , USB is detected but Laptop is not booting through USB. It is starting normally so please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: I hope I'm understanding your question. Are you trying (unsuccessfully) to boot from a USB drive, and asking for a way to be able to boot from USB?

Answer (score 2):

Try going into the BIOS and setting USB as the first boot option from the list. Perhaps HDD is before the USB. Also, if you made this USB yourself you will need to ensure it is bootable.

Comment: The G470 doesn't have that option... It's a bummer. I have the 570 and was excited to use Ubuntu on a thumb drive when I learned the hard way. I ended up using the optical drive option. I still give a +1 because that should be the logical way to address the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no problem in your pen drive, maybe there's a problem in the OS you have in your pen drive. I suggest you use WinToFlash(By Novicorp) or other software that can attach your OS to your pen drive.

Answer (score 0):

The Lenovo G470 doesn't have the capacity to boot from a USB drive. The BIOS BOOT options (use f2 to access while booting) are DVD drive, HDD and Legacy PCI device. You might be able to update the BIOS, but out of the box, it's not an option...

Here's a [link](http://mobilesupport.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/DS018378) to a BIOS update page.

******  USE CAUTION WHEN DOWNLOADING AND UPDATING YOUR SYSTEM BIOS. I AM BY NO MEANS RECOMMENDING THAT YOU UPDATE YOUR BIOS!!! ********

another option is to create a boot CD/DVD and use the optical drive option in BIOS.